# What does "embedding" mean in context of low-level tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, embedding

I meet the following sentence on page https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/eager/custom_training:

> For Variables representing embeddings TensorFlow will do sparse
>   updates by default, which are more computation and memory efficient.

and completely don't understand it. Please, explain it for me!

Answer (score 0):

An embedding is a mapping from a discrete domain to a vector of real numbers.

Just image to have a `tf.Variable` with shape `[key, value]` where `key` is the dimension of the discrete domain (e.g. a list of words) and `value` is the dimension of the vector that represents `key` (usually this vector is a latent representation of the key).

Tensorflow represents the embedding mapping using a variable and it allows to access the `key` element to get the corresponding `value` using `tf.nn.embedding_lookup`.

Hence, instead of working on the complete embedding (that's a huge variable) tensorflow is able to access only to the `key` element of that variable (sparse access), being more efficient.